# Enable Checkbox Messenger (with Shopify apps)

Tags: facebook, shopify, messenger

I tried to sign up to be notified when I can enable the Checkbox Plugin in the default checked state on my website,

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxe3z.png)

So I went through this Facebook URL:
https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/372670903137094?hc_location=ufi

It's been one month I am waiting, and still nothing

I tried to contact the Facebook service, but they couldn't tell me, and adviced me to contact facebook.stackoverflow.com

So here I am

I have no way to verify the process, so I don't know if you have any idea regarding this

I know it's possible to create an app for this (as seen there: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/checkbox-plugin)

However, I have a Shopify built app that already has that
Its name is Tobi (a well-known equivalent is Recart)

The only difference with the desired result is that it doesn't have the checkbox checked by default (which is why I had to go through the first facebook URL)

Any idea?
Let me know thanks!

Comment: I don’t think anyone here can do much for you in this regard, you will simply have to wait until Facebook gets back to you on the issue.

Comment: ok thanks for clarifying :)